# Count to show 0 when no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
select dc.dateasdate as 'Date', count(Practice) as 'Total Enquiries', dp.practice, de.Origin
from dim.Practice dp
    left join fact.enquiry fe on fe.PracticeSKey = dp.PracticeSKey
        left join dim.EnquiryOrigin de on de.EnquiryOriginSKey = fe.EnquiryOriginSKey and de.Origin = 'Web Enquiry'
            left join dim.Calendar dc on dc.CalendarSKey = fe.EnquiryCreatedSKey
                where dc.dateasdate = '2016-04-03' 
group by dc.dateasdate , de.Origin,practice
order by dc.dateasdate ,Practice
```

It won't show when there's a 0 `Practice`.

Can anyone help me? I've been stuck on this for a few days.

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` clause and put the condition in the last `LEFT JOIN`, i.e. `LEFT JOIN dim.Calendar dc
 ON dc.CalendarSKey = fe.EnquiryCreatedSKey
 AND dc.dateasdate = '2016-04-03'`

Answer (score 5):

The `WHERE` condition effectively turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. You should put the condition in the last `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    dc.dateasdate AS 'Date',
    COUNT(Practice) AS 'Total Enquiries',
    dp.practice,
    de.Origin
FROM dim.Practice dp
LEFT JOIN fact.enquiry fe
    ON fe.PracticeSKey = dp.PracticeSKey
LEFT JOIN dim.EnquiryOrigin de
    ON de.EnquiryOriginSKey = fe.EnquiryOriginSKey
    AND de.Origin = 'Web Enquiry'
LEFT JOIN dim.Calendar dc
    ON dc.CalendarSKey = fe.EnquiryCreatedSKey
    AND dc.dateasdate = '2016-04-03'
GROUP BY
    dc.dateasdate,
    de.Origin,
    practice
ORDER BY dc.dateasdate, Practice
```

Comment: THANK YOU! such a rookie mistake i wont make again!

Comment: but im having an issue with the date now, i need to show the date as the date and not null..

Comment: SELECT
   dc.dateasdate as 'Date',
   case WHEN dc.dateasdate is null THEN '0' ELSE COUNT(Practice) END AS 'Total Enquiries',
    dp.practice,
    de.Origin
FROM dim.Practice dp
LEFT JOIN fact.enquiry fe
    ON fe.PracticeSKey = dp.PracticeSKey
LEFT JOIN dim.EnquiryOrigin de
    ON de.EnquiryOriginSKey = fe.EnquiryOriginSKey
    AND de.Origin = 'Web Enquiry'
LEFT JOIN dim.Calendar dc
    ON dc.CalendarSKey = fe.EnquiryCreatedSKey
    AND dc.dateasdate = '2016-04-03'
 where de.Origin is not null
GROUP BY
    dc.dateasdate,
    de.Origin,
    practice
ORDER BY dc.dateasdate,

Comment: Please post another question for that.